# How to reset teminal under mac os x

Tags: mac, terminal

I would like to reset completely terminal window. Not 'clear' - old outputs are still there, when u scroll up. It is especially useful during reading some debugger output, to have one attempt in termial (it takes hundreds of lines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command-K should do the trick. (or `View > Clear Scrollback`)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, try "View" > "Clear Scrollback ⌘K"

Answer (score 0):

Use the shortcut: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> or View -> Clear Scrollback.

However, if you messed up the encoding of the Terminal by piping output incorrectly, you should first call the `reset` command to re-initialize the it.