# How to reset teminal under mac os x programmatically

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

Similar to the question [How to reset teminal under mac os x](https://superuser.com/questions/70111/how-to-reset-teminal-under-mac-os-x), I was wondering how to reset the scrollback buffer of a mac osx terminal window from a script.

I know I can hit Cmd-K to reset it manually, but I often forget to do this before running a script with a lot of output.  It would be easier to remove the scrollback buffer at the beginning of my script.  The "clear" command doesn't reset the scrollback buffer, so when I scroll up I still see the previous scripts output.

Comment: Not sure if it works on Mac OS X (on Linux it does), but try `reset`.

Comment: reset does not clear the screen or the scrollback buffer on macosx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear the terminal screen & scrollback buffer

Make sure access for assistive devices is enabled in the "Universal Access" System Preference

Take 2:

Command-K = Clear Scrollback, and Terminal supports Applescript:

```
function clear_screen() {
   /usr/bin/open -a Terminal
   /usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "k" using command down'
   return 0
}
```

This can then be Invoked by running:

```
clear_screen
```

Via: http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/1738

Comment: This only clears the screen in macosx.  It does not clear the scrollback buffer.

Comment: I found another method, see my edited answer